# Decrypting PGP using a bat file with unattended password

Tags: batch-file, gnupg, loopback, pgp

i am new to PGP and i am trying to setup a bat file to decrypt my files to load into Automated Task.  i was able to put together a bat file that worked however it kept prompting me for a password even though it was included in my bat command.  Deeper research i found that gpg-agent needs to allow loopback as mentioned here https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2015-May/029851.html So when i include --pinentry-mode loopback it now loops infinitely! If i remove it from my bat statement it still loops infinitely! without decrypting anything.  Furthermore i have to force close the window.
Here is the command i am using..

```
echo MyPassPhrase | gpg -v  --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-fd 0 --force-mdc -d testing.file.pgp
```

Even if i use..

```
gpg -v -o test.txt --force-mdc -d testing.file.pgp
```

it loops infinitely!

Something is obviously wrong.  I am using the GnuPG version 2.2.8.  Thinking i should downgrade??  Been having a lot of issues with this version.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `--passphrase mypassphrase` option?

Answer (score 0):

Never had any issues using this syntax

```
gpg --batch --passphrase somepassphrase -o  "Outfile.txt" --decrypt "Input.pgp"
```

Got a couple dozen automated tasks that do this several times a day.

Comment: I was using that originally however it would still prompt for passphrase.  Now it loops regardless

Comment: What version are you using apparently since 2.1 it requires that pinentry mode

Comment: @user2666821, your examples shows you are using `--passphrase-fd`.  I am using `--passphrase`.

Comment: i just tried your example thank you.  However it prompts me for a passphrase. Yes i included my passphrase